# Send Admob report to an email address

Tags: admob

I saw that there is an optuon to create reports in admob console, though I couldn't find any place in the console to schedule a daily report and automaticlly send it to a specific email.

Is it possible or do I have to code it using admob and gmail api?

Comment: to get started https://developers.google.com/admob/api/v1/libraries

Comment: Yes this is through api. My question is if this possible through their ui console, without coding?

Comment: not possible on UI. API is the way to go